# What's the difference between desktop processor and server processor?

Tags: central-processing-unit

We are thinking in to buy a new server but around here the server motherboards are not easy to get so we are thinking in to buy a mother for an AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3960X and a mother for it but since is not a server processor we don't know what to expect.

Currently we have a dual Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz server that fulfill our needs and now we are looking for something similar o better.
Also we expect to have a better post a boot times.

Another question It is possible to have a second power supply in desktop mother board as a backup for the main one? Worth it?
We never has any trouble with a server PSU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none, particularly when you talk Threadripper, where you CAN plug in ECC memory and where the boards are super high quality.

What you obviously do loose out is KVM capability and premade systems in a decent form factor. I am using Dual EPYC servers in 1U form factor with 12 hard discs (10x2.5" at the front, 2x SATA boot drives on micro style USB sticks, supermicro calls them SataDOM).

Anything that goes into a higher end server in a server room (passive cooling for the CPU, redundant high performance fans, bios integrated fan control, KVM, redundant power supplies) you loose out on, but those are NOT processor issues.

The 39060x is a very fine processor and is very comparable to higher end serve rprocessors, period.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Thought that KVM was part of Linux as a software not a hardware feature(mtoherboard side). AMD-V & AMD-Vi are a different thing?

Comment: KVM properly done is what you can use to update and change bios settings WITHOUT INSTALLED OPERATING SYSTEM. Yes, remove login is part of any modern OS - but how do you fix  boot failure ;) This  proper KVM is always a separate hardware - even if integraeted into the same process.

Comment: @E_Blue KVM here stands for (remote) "Keyboard, Video & Mouse"

Comment: Yeah, it is NOT KVM as the virtualization software (which obviously is software and a hypervisor).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first of all, it is possible to provide a secondary PSU to a mainboard, e.g. by the help of this [Phanteks Power Combo device](http://www.phanteks.com/PH-PWCOB.html). Important things to consider (which this device does automatically) is sending a power-good signal to both connected PSUs so they will keep running.

Desktop processors and server processors differ in their use cases and thus in their overall design. E.g. server CPUs require different chipsets than desktop CPUs, they usually have more, but slower clocked cores (especially relevant for virtualization/multithreading environments) and - this is really relevant - ECC support for memory, which desktop systems (usually) can't provide.
The server chipset also may not provide many High-Speed USB lanes or comparable, but support for other, enterprise-grade high-speed connections and remote management.

There might be many more reasons, but it boils down mainly to redundancy/low error rates.

What I really cannot understand is why you want better boot times. A server is a system designed to run 24/7 (and operate in higher temperature environments) - not something to be rebooted frequently.

Comment: Thanks for your input. We want better POST and boot times because, although it is usually not necessary to reboot when we need to we run in to a rush because the server, in addition to the usual web and database tasks, it receive data from  thousand of IoT security devices, so every minute is very important to us. Also, around here we have some issues with the wall supply, mainly in summer and when that happen Murphy do it job.

Comment: Then your architecture sucks. Sorry. You should have redundancy - and IOT device issues should go on a cloud service preferably and then be forwarded to your own servers. But an IOT endpoint that is not hardware redundant (including internet connection) is an achitectural failure.

Comment: @TomTom And that's why we are thinking in to buy a new server.

Comment: I would not. I would, as I said it, run that to a cloud service. FUll redundancy provided. Then queue it there and pull it for processing down, depending on time sensitivity.

Comment: @TomTom As far I understand a cloud service is not free. Also the server must to receive data from the IoT devices, store it on a DB and answer to the IoT device that the packet was received and send new commands to the IoT devices. Also the server need to know the previous data received to make odometer calculations. I can't have the data distributed among several servers; I need all the data in all DBs. How do you do that in a cloud? And if I put all the system in a cloud our server will have no purpose.

Comment: "As far I understand a cloud service is not free" - a newserver is also not free and your time is also not free. This is a place for professionals, not freeloaders. I value my time and seriously, I can not compete with cloud uptime if I wanted to. The rest is called "programming for not total beginners" because a small service and forwarding the dfata back to a queue to be read by the local server is something I would ask a senior developer to diagrm in an interview - it is not black magic. Noone says to put ALL services in the cloud, and IF you do that - you safe the money for the server.

Comment: "A cloud  service is not free" - That's true. But your servers usually do not run from just nothing, they require power and maintenance - which are both cost points. It might be easier for you to use a cloud service - it scales better to your needs and you got, like @TomTom already mentioned, superior redundancy (especially if I hear about a faulty "wall supply" which cuts mains power for a server "thousand" of IoT devices depend on)

Comment: My main issuie would be uptime. I run a pretty large outfit for a small IT company, but all redundancy stops on our fiber internet connection. Even if I can afford a high available backend (which I can), and batteries, the occasional intenet outage is 100x more likely than in a data center.